# Фрагменты полученные из FragmentManager отобразить в TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment-manager

В tabLayout вместе с ViewPager использую FragmentPagerAdapter , в методе `public Fragment getItem(int position)` я возвращаю `new Fragment` . И всё работает. Из SupportFragmentManager я получаю по тегу имеющиеся фрагменты, очищаю фрагмент менеджер синхронным методом. И уже в новой активности вместо того чтобы использовать new Fragment , я подаю фрагменты из статической коллекции. Но ViewPager пустой.
 Я запутался, разве я не могу получить, допустим из активности, экземпляр уже запущенного фрагмента, сохранить его в статическое поле, перейти на новую активность и там использовать этот статический экземпляр?  Я понимаю что это неправильно, но ради понимания сущности фрагмента, хочется разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь "закешировать" созданные фрагменты в список в первом активити, и при открытии второй активити вытащить из первой этот список и применить к ViewPager?

Когда открывается новая активность - предыдущая переходит в onPause, т.е. в состояние, когда Android может убить процесс активити в любой момент, и доставать из неё какие-то данные (публичные свойства) нет смысла.

Можно конечно попытаться хранить список готовых экземпляров фрагментов в singleton классе Application - он живёт до тех пока приложение не прибили. Но какой смысл?

Comment: я в вопросе говорю как раз о хранении экземпляров в статическом поле(не в списке первой активности), можете считать в singleton. Это раз.  При переходе первой активности в onPause, она передает ссылки на фрагменты в этот синглетон, поэтому когда текущая активность уйдет onStop или даже уничтожется в связи с нехваткой памяти, сами эти фрагменты сборщик мусора не заберет, т.к. в синглтон хранятся ссылки на них. И вот новой активности я хочу "запустить" эти фрагменты.

Comment: Но поведение ViewPager странное. Табы есть, но чистые страницы и когда я пытаюсь переключить свайпом, то индикатор(подсветка текущего таба) не переходит к новому табу, а застревает где то между, как будто он двигается с сильным трением и я его еле перетаскиваю )

Comment: А вот какой в этом смысл, уже другой вопрос. Иногда нужно иметь возможность использовать фрагмент с состоянием из прошлой активности, в новой активности.

Comment: Это костыль. Используйте ViewModel и LiveData. Фрагмент может подписываться на ViewModel и при любых изменениях в LiveData вы получаете возможность реагировать мгновенно. см. https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/527-urok-4-viewmodel.html

Comment: В своем вопросе, я разобрался, чтобы отобразить кешированные фрагменты, мне надо было финишировать страницу, где в данный момент они находятся в onStop . Да знаю, что это костыль и умнее записывать состояние в БД либо хранить в презентере, который будет жить отдельно от активности, как это реализовано с помощью фрейморка Moxy.   В LiveDate возможно тоже получится сохранить состояние, но я плохо представляю как это возможно.. У меня 10 табов с фрагментами, открывается новая активность и я хочу отобразить из них 5 табов с состоянием из прошлой активности..

Comment: не понимаю, как LiveDate поймет что этим фрагментам нужны эти состояния. Может фрагмент новый подпишется и получит данные, но какие из 10 сохранных экземпляров данных.. В прочем возможно это все реализуемо и я просто не знаком с LiveDate. За полезную ссылку спасибо, и за ответ, но он больше как альтернативный ход, чем решение вопроса возникшего при моем варианте реализации

Comment: LiveData отправляет всем подписанным на него компонентам данные при любом изменении - это как широковещательное сообщение: кто подписан на LiveData - тот получит сообщение.